# Create JAR file as Aggregation in maven multi module package

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have following architecture

[image]

Now if i am creating parent child relationship and building child first and parent end it will working fine

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**Requirements :**

I need packaging with following features :

Command run on parent project "A"  - mvn clean install package etc
First create Jar "B" ,"C","D" 
then create Jar "A" 
then add "B","C","D" jar inside Jar A

When i am adding modules

```
  <modules>
        <module>../B</module>
         <module>../C</module>
         <module>../D</module>
    </modules>
```

then maven force to add

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

insted of

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

**Issue :**

When i am adding  packaging pom so jar "A" is not crearing

SO i have tried to create one super pom

[image]

**POM Super :**

```
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../A</module>

    </modules>
```

**POM A:**

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
        <artifactId>Super</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

 <modules>
        <module>../B</module>
         <module>../C</module>
         <module>../D</module>
    </modules> 


<dependencies>

        <!-- B -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- C -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- D-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
            <artifactId>D</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**POM B:**

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
```

**POM C:**

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
   <parent>
        <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

**POM D:**

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
        <groupId>com.khan.vaquar</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

**Problem :** maven not allow to add jar if we are adding module , so how can i add child jar into parent jar and create build .

Comment: What is the exact error? I think in that scenario you need to specify the relativePath to the parent for the reactor build to work.

Comment: Jar A (A contain cihild jar B,C,D) not creating using <packaging>pom</packaging>  and maven not allowed <packaging>jar</packaging> if we add any module 
,

Comment: looking workaround solution how to do that

Comment: Why don't you use a seperate reactor to build the dependencies (B, C, D)? Alternatively I think you could use the super pom as a reactor and add all 4 artifacts (A, B, C, D) after changing A to packaging jar

Comment: B,C,D independent jars but A jar contain its owncode and B,C,D inside of A. independent reactor will create 4 jars independently .A,B,C,D not A( B,C,D,)

Comment: What do you mean by contains? So A is a fat jar (uber jar) that contains the classes of the other three? Or do you literally want to include the jars B,C,D in A?

Comment: Yes A is fat jar,  B,C,D are microservices and saving cost on cloud aggregating all while deploy so add all jars into jar A, and it's also contain spring boot dependency

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create fat jar from multiple modules you can use **maven-shade-plugin** in A project
as

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-fat-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.nk.test.Application</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                    <finalName>A</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

For your example you can create structure as

parent module

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
   <module>../C</module>
   <module>../B</module>
   <module>../A</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Core project  A with maven-shade-plugin and project B & C as dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>A</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <artifactId>B</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
   </dependency>
     <dependency>
   <artifactId>C</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
   <plugins>
   **<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-fat-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.nk.test.Application</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                    <finalName>A</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>**
   </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Dependency module B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Dependenc Module C

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.nk.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>C</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

run maven install on parent project.

This will result in Fat jar named named **A.jar** with  **B** and **C** as  dependencies inside it.

you can find example at :  https://github.com/nomanbplmp/maven-multimodule-fat-jar